# How to configure TestClusterBuilder such that the test cluster has access to SMSProvider?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, orleans

I am trying to follow their tutorial for tests:
[Link to Orleans test docs](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/docs/tutorials_and_samples/testing.html)

But the configuration shown is pretty simplistic:

```
var builder = new TestClusterBuilder();
var cluster = builder.Build();
cluster.Deploy();
```

And does not show how to add SMSProvider.

Let's say that I have the following test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task SaysHelloCorrectly()
    {
        var hello = _cluster.GrainFactory.GetGrain<ISomeGrain>(Guid.NewGuid(), "<Some stream ID>", "Some.Class.Path");
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var streamProvider = _cluster.Client.GetStreamProvider("SMSProvider");
        var photoStream = streamProvider.GetStream<string>(guid, "<Some stream ID>");
        await photoStream.OnNextAsync("Hi");
        Assert.Equal("Hello, World", "Hello, World");
    }
```

Then I get an error in line:

```
var streamProvider = _cluster.Client.GetStreamProvider("SMSProvider");
```

Such as:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.02]     Tests.SaysHelloCorrectly [FAIL]
Failed Tests.FilterTests.SaysHelloCorrectly [8 ms]
Error Message:
  System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : SMSProvider
```

I think that configuring the ClusterFixture correctly would be part of the solution or maybe the way I am getting the StreamProvider in the unit test is not correct.

All of the code looks like the following:

ClusterCollection:

```
using System;
using Orleans.TestingHost;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests {

    [CollectionDefinition(ClusterCollection.Name)]
    public class ClusterCollection : ICollectionFixture<ClusterFixture>
    {
        public const string Name = "ClusterCollection";
    }
}
```

ClusterFixture:

```
public class ClusterFixture : IDisposable
{
    private sealed class Configurator : ISiloBuilderConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(ISiloHostBuilder siloBuilder)
        {
            siloBuilder.AddSimpleMessageStreamProvider("SMSProvider");
            siloBuilder.AddMemoryGrainStorage("PubSubStore");
        }
    }
    public ClusterFixture()
    {
        var builder = new TestClusterBuilder();
        builder.AddSiloBuilderConfigurator<Configurator>();
        this.Cluster = builder.Build();
        this.Cluster.Deploy();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Cluster.StopAllSilos();
    }

    public TestCluster Cluster { get; private set; }
}
```

SomeTests:

```
 [Collection(ClusterCollection.Name)]
    public class SomeTests
    {
        private readonly TestCluster _cluster;

        public SomeTests(ClusterFixture fixture)
        {
            _cluster = fixture.Cluster;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task SaysHelloCorrectly()
        {
            var hello = _cluster.GrainFactory.GetGrain<ISomeGrain>(Guid.NewGuid(), "<Some stream ID>", "Some.Class.Path");
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var streamProvider = _cluster.Client.GetStreamProvider("SMSProvider");
            var photoStream = streamProvider.GetStream<string>(guid, "<Some stream ID>");
            await photoStream.OnNextAsync("Hi");
            Assert.Equal("Hello, World", "Hello, World");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup needs to be improved. You can check this sample from the official Orleans GitHub page: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/main/test/TesterInternal/StreamingTests/SMSStreamingTests.cs

So, in your `ClusterFixture` class you should add the `SiloConfigurator`:

```
private class SiloConfigurator : ISiloConfigurator
{
  public void Configure(ISiloBuilder hostBuilder) =>
     hostBuilder.AddSimpleMessageStreamProvider("SMSProvider")
                .AddMemoryGrainStorage("PubSubStore");
}
```

and the `ClientConfiguretor`:

```
private class ClientConfiguretor : IClientBuilderConfigurator
{
  public void Configure(IConfiguration configuration, IClientBuilder clientBuilder) => 
    clientBuilder.AddSimpleMessageStreamProvider("SMSProvider");
}
```

And then in your `ClusterFixture` constructor:

```
public ClusterFixture()
{
    var builder = new TestClusterBuilder();
    builder.AddSiloBuilderConfigurator<SiloConfigurator>();
    builder.AddClientBuilderConfigurator<ClientConfiguretor>();
    this.Cluster = builder.Build();
    this.Cluster.Deploy();
}
```